# Multiple dex files error when downloading my library from Sonatype

Tags: android, maven

I have developed a library that has been around for some months, and I'm having a problem when downloading it from Sonatype repositories (uploading it works fine).

My library is [MaterialList](https://github.com/dexafree/MaterialList), and it can be imported by

1. Adding this line to your build.gradle file

   ```
   compile 'com.github.dexafree.materiallist:2.1.0'
   ```
2. Cloning the project and adding the library as a module by hand

For testing, you can just clone the repo and try both options, changing the app/build.gradle line, from compile project() to the one in the first option

When you compile and run by setting the `compile project` option, it works perfectly.

But when it's downloaded from Sonatype, it complains about multiple dex files defining a class on a library I need inside my library.

The full trace is the following:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /[sdk-path]/android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /[project-path]/MaterialList/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/[project-path]/MaterialList/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nhaarman/listviewanimations/util/Swappable;
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Any suggestion about how to make it not happen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lib-manipulation` and `lib-core-slh` both depend on `lib-core` themselves. As I see no reference to any StickyListHeaders stuff in your library, I don't think you need the `lib-core-slh` dependency. You should also be able to remove the `lib-core` dependency, since `lib-manipulation` includes this for you.

You could also try to include the dependencies directly, without the `@aar` suffix. Perhaps this messes things up.

```
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0'
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0'
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0'
```

This could be an error on my part though. Let me know if any of these solutions work for you.

Comment: It looks like it's fixed now (I hope, at least now it's working). Thanks!